# userdata .sh script not running on startup for cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I need to run a .sh script on startup of ec2 created from cloudformation.I am copying script from s3 and then trying to run it. The script is able to be copied from the s3 bucket to ec2 root but its not running when we try `.  setupec2.sh` . The script has no issues when run manually (its a bit long as its doing a couple of installations) and I can find it when we login into ec2 but wanted to run it from cloudformation startup and so gave it as user data.

The error its giving is 
`/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 33: setupec2.sh: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a full path when you call `setupec2.sh`
EG `/setupec2.sh` if it is in the root folder.